# How can I add multiple embeded images with php mailer?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, html-email

I'm using **PHP MAILER** to add more than one image for a confirmation message when users sign up to my site. This is the code to add the logo image:

```
$mail2->AddEmbeddedImage('images/email/logo.png', 'vlogo');
```

> Now I want to add 5 social media images in svg format to the footer of
>   my message. I have everything set up, but I can't find any information
>   on adding multiple images to php mailer.

**How can I add more than one embedded image to phpmailer?**

Comment: Can you not just call `AddEmbeddedImage` again? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but I will try to add AddEmbededImage again and see what happens. Is that the standard procedure for phpmailer?

Comment: calling it as many times as needed is standard

Comment: Yep, just call it again, providing a different `cid` value for each.